# On the converse of Lagrange's theorem

Tags: finite-groups

We know that the order of an element in a finite group must divides the order of the group by Lagrange theorem. Is the converse true ? How do we prove it. I know that the converse is true for nilpotent groups.

Comment: There is no element of order $6$ in $\;A_4\;$ , which is of order $12$...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).